# How to pass file as query variable in the graph-gophers

Tags: go, graphql

I have recently implemented the logic for file upload in the graph-gophers repository(FORKED). My logic is working fine as expected when uploading the file using the postman but when I don't know how to pass the file as a query variable on the UI of the Graph-Gophers(Trying it for so many days.)

Any help would be appreciated.

In the below screenshot, I have marked the place where I want to pass the file as an input.

[image]

It is working fine when sending the request using Postman.

[image]